# How to validate and remove unwanted string from invalid json

Tags: json, java-8

I have a invalid Json like below,

```
ERROR:some string here{
"array": [
1,
2,
3
],
"boolean": true,
"color": "gold",
"null": null,
"number": 123,
"object": {
"a": "b",
"c": "d"
},
"string": "Hello World"
}
```

Now i want to remove **ERROR:some string here** and how to get valid json.

Comment: Can you  be more specific how the **ERROR:some string here look** like. Also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to find the position of the first `"{"` and the use `substring` to remove the part before that:

```
String jsonString = input.substring(input.indexOf("{"));
```